# Is it possible to get this page to run smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm using a bunch of jQuery and some of the functions are running a little clunky. Some of the same functions on other pages are running smooth. I was wondering if someone might be able to spot something in my code that might explain why its studdering some of the movement.

You can see it here: http://www.kerrydean.ca/main.html.

Comment: What's slow on the page? I don't notice anything immediately - in fact it looks like most of the page is Flash, which has little to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) with success for finding these types of issues. It is a add-on to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) which is a add-on to [Firefox](http://www.firefox.com).

Comment: thanks guys, unning firebug, but I m a bit lost. must easier than Im making it out to be. Can you pls give me a qucik tip? Not sure what I m doing here

Answer (score 2):

Run Firefox with the Firebug plugin to profile your javascript.  See where it is slowing down.  Alternatively, use Safari or Chrome with the developer console. They also have the ability to do javascript profiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firefox firebug profiling to find some issues in your code

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

This can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good guideline.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

1. Move your script references to the
   bottom instead of the top.
2. Firebug is a GREAT TOOL. Also use
   it's error
       console to see if you have
       javascript errors.
3. You are loading
           jquery version 1.3.2 & 1.4 for some
           reason
4. Instead of referencing images directly, create classes in your external style sheet and assign those classes to the elements.